# How should I reinit a new db (windows 8 64b)?

Tags: mysql

In the data directory of Mysql some files are corrupt. Recovering is not working anymore. I have a complete sql backup and want to setup a new db. The complete stuff is installed with the use of wampserver.

I just renamed the :
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data
to
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data_old

and made a new folder called 
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data

Changed socket 3306 to 3307 but now getting:

Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

How should I reinit a new db (windows 8 64b)?

Answer (score 0):

you would require mysql folder from the data_old directory. As it looks for mysql related tables whenever you initiate mysql on with some other folder.    Perform following steps in sequence

> 1 stop MySQL instance for old instance
>
> 2 copy data folder or system databases folders(mysql,performace_schema,information_schema,test) folder from  "D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data_old"   to the new path " D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data"
>
> 3 mysqld --install  --defaults-file =Absolute Path to .ini file

If you are successful, the message “Service successfully installed.” will appear

If so you should be able to connect to new MySQL instance with new port.

Hope it helps